# Reading a ByteArray from a FileSystem or a Jar in Kotlin

Tags: jar, kotlin, resources

I am often developing applications in an IDE and then distributing them with an executable JAR.  So I seek interoperability in regards to library functions.  I have a partial solution using an `InputStream` to robustly read data from a file located in either a FileSystem or a Jar file, but I would like to make use of the robust Kotlin function `Closable.use()` to adapt to the error being thrown or not.

After some struggle I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) that explains how compression inside the Jar file makes its access different than that from a FileSystem.  In particular the nice Kotlin extension function `File.readBytes()` will not work for a file in a Jar.  That is a shame because looking into the source of `readBytes()` there is a clever use of the `use()` function to handle the stream contingencies.  It says...

> closes it down correctly whether an exception is thrown or not.

Here is the partial solution which returns a ByteArray. These functions work the same whether running the application from within the IDE or from an executable Jar.

```
inline fun <reified T> getResourceAsStream(filename:String):InputStream {
  //it is calling function's responsibility to close the stream
  //force the first character to be a backslash that indicates root
  val fnameWithPath= if (filename[0] != '/') "/$filename" else filename
  //extract the stream if it exists
  return T::class.java.getResourceAsStream(fnameWithPath)
}
inline fun <reified T> getResourceByteArray(filename:String):ByteArray {
  //will open a stream, read bytes and then close stream
  val stream= getResourceAsStream<T>(filename)
  val byteArray = stream.readBytes()
  stream.close()
  return byteArray
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've read through your question a few times but I fail to see what you are asking. What is your question?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you are right, my question was not clear.  I wanted to know the Kotlin way to properly close the `InputStream` and deal with the possibility of the file not existing or other errors thrown.  As a lead, it seems that this same problem was solved in `File.readBytes()` using the Kotlin library function `use()`. Subsequently, I was successful integrating this `use()` function and posted my solution below.  There may be other issues concerning reading robustly from both the FileSystem and a Jar that I'm missing.  So I'm posting my best idea and looking for any improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  What you might have missed is that Kotlin already defines an extension method [use()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) on the Closable interface, which InputStream implements.  So your second method can be rewritten as a one-liner:

```
inline fun <reified T> getResourceByteArray(filename: String)
    = getResourceAsStream<T>(filename).use{ it.readBytes() }
```

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated @gidds ' solution to make use of the Kotlin library function [Closeable.use()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) as part of the operation to load the *ByteArray* from a resource file through an *InputStream*.  I'm [expecting](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-try-with-resources) the `use()` function to take care of closing the *InputStream* or otherwise dealing with *errors thrown or not*.

In the updated code, the calling *Class* provided as a reified type gives the context for which *resources* directory will contain the file. In a multi-project build, there may be several *resources* directories.  It is the case I'm operating under with different projects requiring different input data.

```
inline fun <reified T> getResourceAsStream(filename:String):InputStream {
  //it is calling function's responsibility to close the stream
  //force the first character to be a backslash that indicates root
  val fnameWithPath= if (filename[0] != '/') "/$filename" else filename
  //extract the stream if it exists
  return T::class.java.getResourceAsStream(fnameWithPath)
}

inline fun <reified T> getResourceByteArray(filename: String)
= getResourceAsStream<T>(filename).use{ it.readBytes() }

class ReadByteData() {
  init{
    val byteArray= getResourceByteArray<ReadByteData>("fileName")
  }
}
```